# Nodejs Try/Catch Block stops executing after defining object

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch

I have a try/catch block that uses the keyword await to handle asynchronous tasks. Everything works except for the fact that my try block stops executing/throws an empty error after defining an new object.

The log statement where it logs the group is the last log I am getting.

```
 // Try to find group
  try {
    let group = await Group.findById(req.params.groupId);

    if (!group) {
      res.status(404).send('Group not found.');
      return;
    }

    if (group.teacher != teacher.id) {
      res.status(401).send('You are not the teacher of this group');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Reached here');
    console.log(group);
    // Create News
    var newNews = {
      title: req.body.title,
      description: req.body.description,
      group: group.id,
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
    };

    console.log(newNews);
    console.log('trying to save');
    group.news.push(newNews);
    console.log('pushed');
    // Save
    try {
      let newGroup = await group.save();
      return res.status(200).send(savedGroup);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }
```

Comment: Not really a solution, but since your two `catch`s do the same thing, might you simply leave off the nested `try` block and let it fall through as normal if something is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your code crashes in the creation of the object.
One of the values of the object is probably causing an exception.

I suggest you add some logging inside your `catch` block.